# Java swing, error, cannot find symbol method getRootPane()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a border to my frame so that it looks better and I have tried lots of things but they all return the same type of error. I am new to Java and so I assume this has something to do with the imports. Here is my code. Please help if you can.

```java
package com.company;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class gui{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Create the window/frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.RED));

        //Creating the MenuBar and adding components
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        JMenuItem m11 = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem m12 = new JMenuItem("Save as");
        m1.add(m11);
        m1.add(m12);
        JMenuItem m21 = new JMenuItem("Wiki");
        JMenuItem m22 = new JMenuItem("More...");
        m2.add(m21);
        m2.add(m22);

        //Create the panel and the contents
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Something I can put here");
        panel1.add(button);

        //Creates a Text Area
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

        //Add contents to the window/frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question does not compile because of the following line:

```java
getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.RED));
```

You need to change it to:

```java
frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.RED));
```

After I did that and ran your code I got:

[image: screen capture of running code]

Does this resolve your problem?

For the sake of completeness, here is the code I ran in order to get the above window.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the window/frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.RED));

        //Creating the MenuBar and adding components
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        JMenuItem m11 = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem m12 = new JMenuItem("Save as");
        m1.add(m11);
        m1.add(m12);
        JMenuItem m21 = new JMenuItem("Wiki");
        JMenuItem m22 = new JMenuItem("More...");
        m2.add(m21);
        m2.add(m22);

        //Create the panel and the contents
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Something I can put here");
        panel1.add(button);

        //Creates a Text Area
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

        //Add contents to the window/frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```